# Python: Can't pop from an empty list

Tags: python

I am creating a python program to detect and enable usb to usb data transfer between usb storage drives. However I am having an issue with updating the `dev_label` (device name of the drive) and passing it to `Exchange`. Here is the code :

```
serial_list=[]
context = Context()
monitor = Monitor.from_netlink(context)
monitor.filter_by(subsystem='block',device_type='partition')
observer = GUDevMonitorObserver(monitor)


def device_connected(observer, device):
    Welcome.device_count+=1

    flag =False
    for iden in serial_list :
        if iden == device.__getitem__('ID_SERIAL_SHORT'):
            flag=True

    if flag ==False:
        serial_list.append(device.__getitem__('ID_SERIAL_SHORT'))
        Welcome.dev_label.append(str(device.__getitem__('ID_FS_LABEL')))
        size = len(Welcome.dev_label)
        label = gtk.Label('Device connected :: {0!r}'.format(Welcome.dev_label[size-1]))
        Welcome.vbox.pack_start(label)
        Welcome.window.show_all()

    if Welcome.device_count<2:
        label = gtk.Label('Connect the second device')
        Welcome.vbox.pack_start(label)
        Welcome.window.show_all()


    else :
        Exchange()

observer.connect("device-added",device_connected)
monitor.start()

class Welcome:
    device_count = 0    
    window = gtk.Window()
    vbox= gtk.VBox(False, 5)
    dev_label = []

    def __init__(self):

        self.window.set_default_size(300, 300)
        self.window.set_title("Welcome")

        label = gtk.Label("Connect the desired device")

        self.vbox.pack_start(label)
        self.window.add(self.vbox)

        self.window.connect("destroy", lambda q: gtk.main_quit())
        self.window.show_all()

class Exchange:
    window1 = gtk.Window(Welcome.dev_label.pop())
    window2 = gtk.Window(Welcome.dev_label.pop())
    def __init__(self):

        width = gtk.gdk.screen_get_default().get_width()
        height = gtk.gdk.screen_get_default().get_height()

        self.window1.resize(width/2,height)
        self.window2.resize(width/2,height)

        self.window2.move(self.window1.get_position()[0]+width/2, self.window1.get_position()[1])

        label = gtk.Label("Hello")
        self.window1.add(label)

        self.window1.connect("destroy" , lambda q : gtk.main_quit())
        self.window1.show_all()

        label = gtk.Label("World")
        self.window2.add(label)

        self.window2.connect("destroy",lambda q : gtk.main_quit())
        self.window2.show_all()        




Welcome()
gtk.main()
```

The error shown in the trace back is  :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "project.py", line 70, in <module>
    class Exchange:
  File "project.py", line 71, in Exchange
    window1 = gtk.Window(Welcome.dev_label.pop())
IndexError: pop from empty list
```

I can't figure out how to synchronize all these event so that the compiler doesn't throw an error. Values are being popped from `Welcome.dev_label` only after they've been updated in `device_connected` so why does the compiler have a problem? I am a python newbie so please be gentle.

Comment: prefer `if not flag` to `if flag ==False`

Answer (score 0):

This is not the compiler givin errors but the program.

You can change your class to this:

```
import time
class Exchange:
    while not Welcome.dev_label: time.sleep(0.001)
    window1 = gtk.Window(Welcome.dev_label.pop()) # line 4
    while not Welcome.dev_label: time.sleep(0.001)
    window2 = gtk.Window(Welcome.dev_label.pop())
```

This would be kind of a synchronization primitive given that only line 4 and 6 remove content.
In general you would use a queue for this.

```
import queue # Python3 # import Queue Python 2
Welcome.dev_label # = queue.Queue()
Welcome.dev_label.put(...) # instead of append
Welcome.dev_label.get(...) # instead of pop
```

But I do not know wether your code uses threads and runs in parallel. If the `time.sleep` example works then you can switch to a queue.

Comment: I haven't used any threads. The entire encode is posted in the question.

Comment: `monitor.start()` is usually an indicator for a thread. Is there anything in the list if you wait? Then you have threads.

Comment: I used a queue and the above methods. However when the program is executed nothing happens. The cursor simply goes to the next line and keeps blinking.

Comment: If `IndexError: pop from empty list` does not occur then this a a good sign. Nothing happens.. what does this mean? The code shoudl wait until the two devices are connected.

Comment: Well nothing else is happening either.

Comment: What do you expect? Can you put prints in the lines and then say in which order they should execute?